# How to show command line box in the Log of P4V

Tags: command-line, p4v

I am using P4V on my computer and I am able to see a text box right under the Log where I can input command lines. If I press the button to close the log, that text box disappears with it, and then if I go to View -> Log, it reappears.

However, the other members of my team, in P4V on their computer, they only see the Log, they don't see the text box to input command lines. How can they make it show up?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For those who looks for the answer to this, it seems that the command line bar in the Log was removed after P4V 2017.2

If you want that command line, simply download that version or earlier.